# Есть ли какое-то автоматическое создание массивов?

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Дана строка, нужно разделить на слова и записать в отдельные массивы.
В голову не приходит мысля как сделать автосоздание массивов.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: А Вы слышали что-нибудь про *динамические* массивы?

Comment: @Firepro я знаю что такое многомерные и динамические массивы, НО вы наверное не поняли меня. Я незнаю сколько будет слов - исходя из этого - я незнаю сколько должно быть массивов. Это не вписывать в один массив, а в разные......ииилии здесь нужно все позаписывать в динамический многомерный массив, а в нем каждая новая строка - это и есть новый одномерный массив?

Comment: @Anonim Естественно лучше записывать в один многомерный массив и в нем каждая строка будет новый одномерный массив, создавать переменные с разными названиями на ходу выполнения программы у вас не получится, хотя можно использовать кодогенерацию, но это костылище.

Comment: @Firepro Обсуждение привело к ответу))спасибо)

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

В C++ статически определенные массивы должны иметь размеры, заданные при компиляции константным выражением.

Если вы заранее не знаете размер массива, то вам придется распределять его динамически и, возможно, перераспределять.

Вместо вручную распределенных динамических массивов вы можете использовать стандартные контейнеры, как, например стандартный контейнер `std::vector`.

Что касается C, то опционно он может поддерживать массивы переменной длины (Variable Length Arrays - VLA).

Если ваш компилятор языка C поддерживает VLA, то вы можете их использовать.